# Send data object from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

i have fragment(film) to show json data. now i want to send data( object) to activity( this class make show full inofrmation ). But i dont know get and send data in method onClick. who can show me some sugguest ?? Many thank .
Here is my code.

```
public class FragmentFilmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentFilmAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<InforFilm> inforFilms;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getmImageLoader();
    //contructor
    public FragmentFilmAdapter(List<InforFilm> inforFilms) {
        this.inforFilms = inforFilms;
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        NetworkImageView thumbNail;
        TextView gender;
        TextView rating;
        TextView title;
        TextView year;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.film_thumbnail);
            gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.film_genre);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.film_title);
            rating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.film_rating);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.film_releaseYear);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_film_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        InforFilm infor = inforFilms.get(position);

        holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(infor.getThumbail(), imageLoader);
        holder.title.setText(infor.getTitle());
        holder.rating.setText(String.valueOf(infor.getRating()));
        holder.year.setText(String.valueOf(infor.getYear()));
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : infor.getGender()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        holder.gender.setText(genreStr);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return inforFilms.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView doesnot have onclick listener of own, so create a listener interface and get the adapter position. 
Please refer this link it may help you
[Getting recyclerview position and passing object on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674100/getting-recyclerview-position-and-passing-object-on-click)

Comment: I try example with onclick to get link and it work. so i want to get objetc( array lisst). but i dont know how to do it ?